# how to write the condition for,either like or unlike buttons clicked

Tags: jquery

my code is...

```
 $(document).on("click", ".mp-likedImgs", function () {
    var mplike= $(this).parent().parent().children().first().attr('id');
    if (jQuery.inArray(mplike, unlikedImgsId) != -1) {
        var delmpLike = unlikedImgsId.indexOf(mplike);
        unlikedImgsId.splice(delmpLike, 1);
    }
        if (jQuery.inArray(mplike, likedImgsId) == -1) {
        likedImgsId.push(mplike);
        $(this).find('img').css({'opacity':'1.0'});
    }
   });

   //start code for multiple image unlike button
      $(document).on("click", ".mp-unlikedImgs", function () {
     var mpunlike= $(this).parent().parent().children().first().attr('id');
     if (jQuery.inArray(mpunlike, likedImgsId) != -1) {
         var delmpUnLike= likedImgsId.indexOf(mpunlike);
         likedImgsId.splice(delmpUnLike,1);
        }
       if (jQuery.inArray(mpunlike, unlikedImgsId) == -1) {
         unlikedImgsId.push(mpunlike); 
         $(this).find('img').css({'opacity':'1.0'});
       }

     });
```

In full screen mode i have like & unlike buttons on image.when i press the like and unlike on image both are clicked & highlighted,but i want only one button is clicked for one image either like or unlike.

thank in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Try with `mp-UniqueImgs` class which is having for both the types.like

```
 $(document).on("click", ".mp-UniqueImgs", function () {
```

I think you are using same functionality.Better to use a unique class name otherthan the present and apply this action on that new class.